# How to take JSON objects one by one from response object and display in table in Angular?

Tags: java, html, angular, typescript, jsonobjectrequest

The JSON Array get into typescript as response Object from my Java application. I need to pick each object and display into html page corresponding to that typescript page in angular. 
**list-user.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-user',
  templateUrl: './list-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-user.component.css']
})
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  jdbc: any;
  username:any

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("session") || "");
    let listuser: any = {
      username: this.username,
    }
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/demoprojectjava/list-user/',
      listuser, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
  });
  }
}
```

**list-user.component.html**

```
<div>
    <h1 class="listuser"> Display Data from Json File </h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{--Here I need value from Json array}}</td>
            <td>{{--Here I need value from Json array}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>  
    </table>
</div>
```

When I run my code, in console I got the output as a result for **console.log(res);** as :

```
{"user_data":[{"user_id":"111","username":"Hridya"},{"user_id":"222","username":"Rizz"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vishnu Prabhu. Thanks for the answer.

 Your Typescript code worked smoothly... But I didn't get value with your html code and made a small change. Then I got the values in the table. So I'm posting the entire code that worked well for me, to anyone else for future reference.
**list-user.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-user',
  templateUrl: './list-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-user.component.css']
})
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  jdbc: any;
  username: any;
  data: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("session") || "");
    let listuser: any = {
      username: this.username
    }

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/demoprojectjava/list-user/',
      listuser, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.body);
        return this.data = res;
      },
      );
  }
}
```

**list-user.component.html**

```
<div>
    <h1 class="listuser"> Display Data from Json File</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let user of data.body.user_data">
                <td>{{user.user_id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the http request as Observable in a property (here `userData$`). Then use the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your template to have angular automatically `subscribe` to it.
Then use [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngFor) to iterate over all the elements inside the response and display the data accordingly.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

type ResponseTypeFromYourBackend = any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-user',
  templateUrl: './list-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-user.component.css']
})
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  jdbc: any;
  username:any
  userData$: Observable<ResponseTypeFromYourBackend>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("session") || "");
    let listuser: any = {
      username: this.username,
    }
    this.userData$ = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/demoprojectjava/list-user/',
      listuser,
      { observe: 'response' }
    );
  }
}


<div>
  <h1 class="listuser"> Display Data from Json File </h1>
  <table *ngIf="userData$ | async as data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User Id</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of data.user_data">
      <td>{{ user.user_id}}</td>
      <td>{{ user.username}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, astonishing how similar our answers are :D Guess this can really be seen as a best practice then :D

Comment: Yes, I really like that you re-mapped `user_data` outside the template already. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to do the following:

1. Define an observable on class level:

```
userData$: Observable<YourType>;
...
ngOnInit() {
   ...
   this.userData$ = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/demoprojectjava/list-user/',
      listuser).pipe(map(item => item.user_data));
  }
```

2. Subscribe to this observable using `async` pipe and iterate over the array:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of userData$ | async">
  <td>{{item.user_id}}</td>
  <td>{{item.username}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to store the response and use ngFor to loop through the array.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-active-census',
  templateUrl: './upload-active-census.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-active-census.component.css'],
})
export class UploadActiveCensusComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  jdbc: any;
  username: any;
  data: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session') || '');
    let listuser: any = {
      username: this.username,
    };
    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8080/demoprojectjava/list-user/', listuser, {
        observe: 'response',
      })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return this.data = res;
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 class="listuser"> Display Data from Json File </h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of data?.user_data">
                <td>{{item.user_id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.username}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This will cause a runtime error the moment `data.user_data` gets evaluated before the request was finished.

Comment: @Vishnu Prabhu. Your Typescript code worked smoothly... But I didn't got value with your html code and made a small change as
            `<tr *ngFor="let user of data.body.user_data">` . Then I got the values in table